# Infragistic ultrawebgrid: After moving scroll bar, row click gets disabled in IE

Tags: asp.net, frontend, infragistics, ultrawebgrid

The page I need to fix has `UltraWebGrid` control on it.

When there are more rows then control can display, scroll bars appear.
When clicking on a row, the data details page is displayed.
However, after trying to scroll, when clicking on a row, nothing happens.
Than when clicking on a columns to sort, clicking begins working again. 
It works under Chrome and Firefox though.
I cannot find solution for this one. Need help.

This is the part of the page that displays the UltraWebGrid:

```
<td align="center"><igtbl:ultrawebgrid id="grdMerchants" runat="server" Height="340px" Width="100%">
  <DisplayLayout AutoGenerateColumns="False" AllowSortingDefault="OnClient" RowHeightDefault="21px"
     RowSizingDefault="Free" Version="3.00" SelectTypeRowDefault="Single" ViewType="OutlookGroupBy"
     HeaderClickActionDefault="SortMulti" BorderCollapseDefault="Separate" AllowColSizingDefault="Free"
     RowSelectorsDefault="No" Name="grdMerchants" TableLayout="Fixed" CellClickActionDefault="Edit" AllowUpdateDefault="Yes">
 <AddNewBox>
    <Style BorderWidth="1px" BorderStyle="Solid" BackColor="LightGray">
      <BorderDetails ColorTop="White" WidthLeft="1px" WidthTop="1px" ColorLeft="White"
      </BorderDetails>
    </Style>
 </AddNewBox>
   <Pager>
      <Style BorderWidth="1px" BorderStyle="Solid" BackColor="LightGray">
        <BorderDetails ColorTop="White" WidthLeft="1px" WidthTop="1px" ColorLeft="White">
        </BorderDetails>
      </Style>
   </Pager>
  <HeaderStyleDefault Font-Size="8pt" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Bold="True" BorderStyle="Solid" ForeColor="#E1E8F5"
    BackColor="#11459E" CustomRules="background-image:url(/ig_common/images/Office2003BlueBG.png);background-repeat:repeat-x;">
    <BorderDetails ColorTop="173, 197, 235" WidthLeft="1px" WidthTop="1px" ColorLeft="173, 197, 235"></BorderDetails>
  </HeaderStyleDefault>
  <FrameStyle Width="100%" BorderWidth="0px" Font-Size="8pt" Font-Names="Verdana" BorderStyle="Solid"
   Height="340px"></FrameStyle>
   <FooterStyleDefault BorderWidth="1px" BorderStyle="Solid" BackColor="LightGray">
      <BorderDetails ColorTop="White" WidthLeft="1px" WidthTop="1px" ColorLeft="White">    </BorderDetails>
   </FooterStyleDefault>
   <EditCellStyleDefault BorderWidth="0px" BorderStyle="None"></EditCellStyleDefault>
   <SelectedRowStyleDefault ForeColor="White" BackColor="#F09D21" CustomRules="background-image:url(/ig_common/images/Office2003SelRow.png);background-repeat:repeat-x;">    </SelectedRowStyleDefault> 
   <RowAlternateStyleDefault BackColor="#E0E0E0"></RowAlternateStyleDefault>
   <RowStyleDefault BorderWidth="1px" BorderColor="Black" BorderStyle="Solid" CssClass="bodytext">
      <Padding Left="3px"></Padding>
      <BorderDetails WidthLeft="0px" WidthTop="0px"></BorderDetails>
   </RowStyleDefault>
</DisplayLayout>
<Bands>
   <igtbl:UltraGridBand>
     <Columns>
        <igtbl:UltraGridColumn HeaderText="MID" Key="" EditorControlID="" Width="145px" Format="" HeaderClickAction="SortMulti" BaseColumnName="MID" FooterText="">
             <ValueList DisplayMember="MID" ValueMember="MID" Key="MID"></ValueList>
             <CellStyle CssClass="bodytext"></CellStyle>
             <Footer Key="" Caption=""></Footer>
             <Header ClickAction="SortMulti" Key="" Caption="MID"></Header>
        </igtbl:UltraGridColumn>
        <igtbl:UltraGridColumn HeaderText="DBA" Key="DBA" EditorControlID="" Width="195px" Format="" HeaderClickAction="SortMulti" BaseColumnName="DBA" FooterText="">
             <ValueList DisplayMember="DBA" ValueMember="DBA" Key="DBA"></ValueList>
             <Footer Key="DBA" Caption=""></Footer>
             <Header ClickAction="SortMulti" Key="DBA" Caption="DBA"></Header>
        </igtbl:UltraGridColumn>
        <igtbl:UltraGridColumn HeaderText="City" Key="loccity" EditorControlID="" Format="" HeaderClickAction="SortMulti" BaseColumnName="loccity" FooterText="">
             <ValueList DisplayMember="loccity" ValueMember="loccity" Key="loccity" </ValueList>
              <Footer Key="loccity" Caption=""></Footer>
              <Header ClickAction="SortMulti" Key="loccity" Caption="City"></Header>
        </igtbl:UltraGridColumn>
        <igtbl:UltraGridColumn HeaderText="State" Key="locst" EditorControlID="" Width="50px" Format="" HeaderClickAction="SortMulti" BaseColumnName="locst" FooterText="">
           <ValueList DisplayMember="locst" ValueMember="locst" Key="locst"></ValueList>
           <Footer Key="locst" Caption=""></Footer>
           <Header ClickAction="SortMulti" Key="locst" Caption="State"></Header>
        </igtbl:UltraGridColumn>
        <igtbl:UltraGridColumn HeaderText="Phone" Key="locphone" EditorControlID="" Format="" HeaderClickAction="SortMulti" BaseColumnName="locphone" FooterText="">
           <ValueList DisplayMember="locphone" ValueMember="locphone" Key="locphone"></ValueList>
           <Footer Key="locphone" Caption=""></Footer>
           <Header ClickAction="SortMulti" Key="locphone" Caption="Phone"></Header>
        </igtbl:UltraGridColumn>
        <igtbl:UltraGridColumn HeaderText="" Key="Client_Id" EditorControlID="" Hidden="True" Format="" BaseColumnName="Client_Id" FooterText="">
            <ValueList DisplayMember="Client_Id" ValueMember="Client_Id" Key="Client_Id"></ValueList>
            <Footer Key="Client_Id" Caption=""></Footer>
            <Header Key="Client_Id" Caption=""></Header>
        </igtbl:UltraGridColumn>
        <igtbl:UltraGridColumn HeaderText="" Key="intmid" EditorControlID="" Hidden="True" Format="" BaseColumnName="intmid" FooterText="">
            <ValueList DisplayMember="intmid" ValueMember="intmid" Key="intmid"></ValueList>
            <Footer Key="intmid" Caption=""></Footer>
            <Header Key="intmid" Caption=""></Header>
        </igtbl:UltraGridColumn>
        <igtbl:UltraGridColumn HeaderText="Queue State" Key="merchantStateDescription" Width="170px" BaseColumnName="merchantStateDescription">
            <Footer Key="merchantStateDescription"></Footer>
            <Header Key="merchantStateDescription" Caption="Queue State"></Header>
        </igtbl:UltraGridColumn>
    </Columns>
   </igtbl:UltraGridBand>
  </Bands>
 </igtbl:ultrawebgrid></td>
```

Why this grid behave like that? Is there something else that is needed to be configured?

Thank's

Answer (score 0):

I found one solution to my problem.

I just added `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9"/>` to `<head>` element.
It seems to be working now, only the amount of records displayed increased.